# Online database/Apis for Shia Hadiths

Tags: hadith, shiism

> Are there any APIs or Online database for shia hadith collections so
>   hadiths can be fetched and used? I can't find any thing :(

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's asking for a service, and the answers are most likely to be filled with links promoting that service.

Answer (score 2):

I search for online api for our hadith but i didnt found so i scrap it from this website https://www.hekm.co/ by python script
I end up creating json files of 2 languge ar and en
This is the link of files that I creat https://www.mediafire.com/file/85hrbtemwmdz7oe/shia.rar/file

I hope you find it useful

Edited : I recently create an Api by scrapping this site https://thaqalayn.net/

my Api link is https://rapidapi.com/a70114995/api/shiaapi

Comment: I've been looking for this for a long time, thank you, but can you tell me how to register?

Comment: It's now free for everyone go on and check it

Answer (score 2):

Salam Alaykum,

I made an API based on thaqalayn.net that can be accessed at https://www.thaqalayn-api.net/

visit the github page to get started: https://github.com/MohammedArab1/ThaqalaynAPI

inshAllah it can be of some use to you :)