# Online databas (sql) for Shia Hadiths

Tags: hadith, shiism

Is there an sql version for shia hadith I saw the api version of it in this post [Online database/Apis for Shia Hadiths](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/48986/online-database-apis-for-shia-hadiths)
but I need an sql version of it can any body help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use an online converter to convert json to sql
use this website https://www.convertjson.com/json-to-sql.htm
and for the json file you can get them from my github :
https://github.com/aliakil/ShiaBookJsonApi/tree/master/ford